# Pipe with piped parameter in angular 2

Tags: angular, pipe, angular-pipe

I'd like to write something like

```
<p>{{"CURRENT_DATE" | translate:(value:(currentDate | date:getDateFormat))}}</p>
```

where `translate` is a pipe function from [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate).

I'd like to display: "Today is 2016-07-13", so `CURRENT_DATE` is `"Today is {{value}}"` and expects a dynamic value.

Depending on the user's locale, the current date format changes. I have a function `getDateFormat` which returns `"yy-MM-dd"` or `"dd/MM/yy"`.

I know it is possible to chain pipes, but my case here is not really chaining pipes.

Is there a simple way, or do I have to write a custom pipe ?

Thanks !

**EDIT**: Okay my bad, I was too dumb to copy the example without errors.
I should have written :

```
<p>{{"CURRENT_DATE" | translate:{value:currentDate | date:getDateFormat } }}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not do something like:

```html
<p>{{"CURRENT_DATE" | translate:{value: getDate()}}}</p>
```

And then `getDate()` function creates the date in the locale required using a combination of the information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Answer (score 1):

This works:

- en.json

  `'DETAIL': 'Liability {{id}} - from {{date}}'`
- template

  `{{ 'DETAIL' | translate: { id: id, date: lastModifiedDate | date: 'medium' } }}`