# Distinct values in select with ngfor - chaining pipes

Tags: angular, typescript

I already did one pipe (search) filter the results but I want a second pipe or another way to filter the search values in options select and show the values only once.

What I need is a dynamic search - select options menu with unique (distinct) values.

The problem:

[image]

Html:

```
<!-- Search form -->
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(value)]="category" placeholder="Categories" [formControl]="panelMargin" panelClass="example-panel">
      <mat-option>None</mat-option>          
      <mat-option value="{{p.category}}" *ngFor="let p of resultCollection| FilterPipe:category:platform">{{p.category}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(value)]="platform" placeholder="Program Languages" [formControl]="panelMargin" panelClass="example-panel">
      <mat-option>None</mat-option>

      <mat-option value="{{p.platform}}" *ngFor="let p of resultCollection | FilterPipe:category:platform">{{p.platform}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <!-- Results -->
  <div id="pr-result" class="section-block">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Platform</th>
      <th>Logo</th>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>Desc</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let r of resultCollection | FilterPipe:category:platform">
      <td>{{r.name}}</td>
      <td>{{r.category}}</td>
      <td>{{r.platform}}</td>
      <td>{{r.logo}}</td>
      <td>{{r.link}}</td>
      <td>{{r.desc}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Component:

```
export class Mydata{
  id: number;
  name:string;
  category: string;
  platform: string;
  logo: string;
  link: string;
  desc: string;
}

export class PortfolioGrComponent implements OnInit {       
   private resultCollection = new Array<Mydata>();
   constructor() { 
this.resultCollection = this.generateResults();
}

generateResults():Mydata[]{
    return [
      {
        id:1,
        name: "i-tech",
        category: "e-shop",
        platform: "Laravel",
        logo: "1",
        link: "1",
        desc: "1"
      },
      ...
    ];
   }
}
```

Filter pipe:

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(_initialCollection: Mydata[], _category: string, _platform:string): Mydata[] {
    let results = new Array<Mydata>();

      _initialCollection.forEach((person,index,collection) => {
        if(_category === null && _platform === null){
            // console.log(prname);
            return results.push(person);
        }
        if(_category && _platform){
            if( person.category.toLowerCase().includes(_category.toLowerCase()) && person.platform.toLowerCase().includes(_platform.toLowerCase()) ){
              results.push(person);
            }
        }
        else if(_category){
            if( person.category.toLowerCase().includes(_category.toLowerCase()) ){
              results.push(person);
            }
        }
        else if(_platform){
            if( person.platform.toLowerCase().includes(_platform.toLowerCase()) ){
              results.push(person);
            }
        }       
      }); 
    return results;
  }
}
```

As you can see my results are connected to my search. What I am trying to do is to create a dynamic search and show the available choices, depending on my results; just like a multiple search filter of an e-shop.

I was thinking a second filter pipe for my search option form but I don't know if it is possible and I didn't find a similar example for helping me out.

How to solve this problem and what way is more appropriate?
If you need some more details please feel free to ask me.

I want to remove duplicate items. Fixing the date it doesn't seems right because in my code I haven't any dates to transform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pipe with piped parameter in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355577/pipe-with-piped-parameter-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to create another pipe and filtering the results like this:

Html:

```
<mat-form-field>
        <mat-select [(value)]="category" placeholder="Categories" [formControl]="panelMargin" panelClass="example-panel">
          <mat-option>None</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="{{p.category}}" *ngFor="let p of resultCollection | FilterPipe:category:platform | uniqueCategory:category">{{p.category}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```

unique-category.pipe.ts:

```
export class UniqueCategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(_initialCollection: Mydata[], _category: string): Mydata[] {
      let results = new Array<Mydata>();

      _initialCollection.forEach((product,index,collection) => {
        if(_category === null || _category){            
             if(collection.map(product => product.category).indexOf(product.category) === index){
                return results.push(product);
             }
        }               
      }); 
        return results;   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can choose:

#### First

As the official documentation says, you can chain the pipes:
https://angular.io/guide/pipes#chaining-pipes

Then in your template code would look like:

```
<mat-option value="{{p.platform}}" *ngFor="let p of resultCollection | FilterPipe:category:platform | anotherPipe">{{p.platform}}</mat-option>
```

#### Second

What you could do as well, is creating another method, within your pipe class which would check for duplicates and push results to the `results` array.

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(_initialCollection: Mydata[], _category: string, _platform:string): Mydata[] {
    let results = new Array<Mydata>();

      _initialCollection.forEach((person,index,collection) => {
        if(_category === null && _platform === null){
            // console.log(prname);
            return results.push(person);
        }
        if(_category && _platform){
            if( person.category.toLowerCase().includes(_category.toLowerCase()) && person.platform.toLowerCase().includes(_platform.toLowerCase()) ){
              results.push(person);
            }
        }
        else if(_category){
            if( person.category.toLowerCase().includes(_category.toLowerCase()) ){
              results.push(person);
            }
        }
        else if(_platform){
            if( person.platform.toLowerCase().includes(_platform.toLowerCase()) ){
              results.push(person);
            }
        }       
      }); 
    return results;
  }

  private pushToResults(item:MyData):void {
    if (results.indexOf(item) > -1) //or any other conditional/check
      results.push(person)
  }
}
```